# what's the relation between Windows media Foundation and Expression Encoder?

Tags: encoding, wmf

whats the relation  between  Expression Encoder and windows Media Foundation ?
is Expression Encoder Independent From WMF or Dependent On it?

Answer (score 1):

Expression Encoder is using DirectShow as its media backbone, the precursor of MF.

At the time Expression Encoder 4 shipped, XP was still an important platform for the EE users and MF isn't supported on XP.

In a nutshell, you can see Expression Encoder and WMF as completely independant media technologies.

**by Eric Juteau Microsoft Employee, Moderator**
Pasted from **msdn** forum